# Material Design and devices restrictions

Tags: android, material-design

I've been wondering about Material Design uses on Android apps and devices' restrictions that it implies.

I have already developped for Android but themes usages seemed really confused at this moment (appcompat and stuff, i never really got it)

But apparently the last google i/o brought some tools to help the usage of Material Design in android apps.

So, my question is, how to properly use Material Design elements without restrict your app to a lot of devices ?

(I hope i'm being clear enough)

Comment: https://www.google.com/design/spec/material-design/introduction.html

Comment: @slanecek i've already looked through this. i didn't seem to answer my question. I'd just like to know if Material Design restrict users' old devices. thanks anyway

Comment: if you only need the looks of material design theme in pre-lollipop devices, You can use the appCompat theme from the support library like this
 `<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
    </style>`
or you can use one of the libraries hosted in github, if you want features  like ripple effect
`https://github.com/ZieIony/Carbon` have a look at this lib

Comment: thanks @sony, but i'd like to use google's libraries only. does it mean that pre-lollipop devices won't be able to run my app ?

Comment: Probably yes the only way provided by google to support legacy versions is to do it using AppCompact Library.

Comment: @Mohamed does that mean that MD was included in AppCompat when MD was created or is it two different things ? (i'm sorry but i'm really confused with android's themes)

Comment: ofcourse it will run in pre-lollipop devices, IF YOU USE THE APP COMPAT THEME AND LIBRARY

Comment: correct me if i'm wrong, but for me, AppCompat is a UI "library" made by google that is supported by some devices. In that logic, Material Design is an update of AppCompat. is that right ?

Comment: Appcompat is supported by all android devices and material design is NOT an update of appcompat

Comment: So if I use AppCompat, every android devices will be able to run my app, and I will be able to use the whole material design tools? But what about old devices, will they be able to display material design too?

Comment: @Devz, check my updated answer for that last one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [Design Appcompat](http://android-developers.blogspot.ru/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html) library to implement *some* Material features to work on pre-Lollypop devices, use real Material styles and components on Lollypop+.

This is done by providing alternative resources (`styles | themes.xml, layouts etc.`) using resource qualifier (`-v21`).

In `values-v21/themes.xml` you put

```
<style name="MyAppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material">
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    ...
```

In `values/themes.xml` you put

```
<style name=”MyAppBaseTheme” parent=”Theme.AppCompat”>
    <item name=”colorPrimary”>@color/primary</item>
    ...
<style name=”MyAppTheme” parent=”MyAppBaseTheme”>  
    <!-- here you put the version-independent stuff -->
```

This way you're cleverly taking advantage of theme overriding, by just swapping the Material-related part and defining everything else a single time.

Note the proper `android:` prefix in non-Appcompat version. That is because in 5+ those attributes are part of the sdk, and in Appcompat they're custom, same class citizens as any of the styleables you define yourself.

Read the [guide on maintaining compatibility](https://developer.android.com/training/material/compatibility.html), it will tell you about providing alternative style resources and splitting the codebase for  post- and pre- 5.0

**UPD** Regarding your question in comments, *will they be able to display material design too?*

[Here is a breakdown of support library version and flavours](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html), the `v*` there indicates the minimum Android version needed to run said lib. E.g. the generic v7 support library will give you the support of *[a subset of]* Material components and styles on devices all the way back to android 2.1

Comment: Ok thanks. Well this is a bit complicated ! Shouldn't it be easier ? :(
So, again, if i got this, i need to acquaint my app's code according to different users' OS versions..

Comment: Yes, you do :) That's the cost of backward compatibility. It's not really that complicated. Or you can just drop support of pre-5.0 OSes and wait till it becomes mainstream version.